# Confluent Connect HTTP Sink Connector fails task despite config set to ignore

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

I have an application that wants to send processed events to a third party application via their API. I set up an HTTP Sink connector from Confluent following their guide. Errors originating from kafka/confluent like wrongly structured events etc. are handled correctly and logged to a DLQ. However, when the connector sends data to the third party application and receives an error response code, the connector retries the REST x amount of times before failing the connector task, thus "killing" the connector and stopping data flow. I have tried to configure my connector according to the docs setting behavior.on.error to ignore / log:

> behavior.on.error
> Error handling behavior setting for handling response from HTTP requests. Must be configured to one of the following:
>
> fail Stops the connector when an error occurs.
>
> ignore Continues to process next set of records. when error occurs.
>
> log Logs the error message to application logs when error occurs and continues to process next set of records.
>
> Type: string
> Default: fail
> Valid Values: one of [fail, log, ignore]
> Importance: low

Checking the configs of the connector after starting it also shows the configs listed properly. Is there any settings that I am setting here that are overriding eachother? Btw, in my connect worker task I am setting the variable

```
CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY :
    value: "All"
```

My connector configs are:

```
"{
    \"topics\":\"xxxxxxx\",
    \"connector.class\":\"io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector\",
    \"consumer.override.auto.offset.reset\": \"largest\",
    \"http.api.url\":\"xxxxxxx\",
    \"reporter.bootstrap.servers\":\"xxxxxxx\",
    \"errors.tolerance\":\"all\",
    \"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name\":\"xxxxxxx\",
    \"behavior.on.error\":\"log\",
    \"report.errors.as\": \"http_response\",
    \"headers\": \"$REQUEST_HEADERS\",
    \"https.ssl.protocol\":\"TLSv1.2\",
    \"auth.type\":\"OAUTH2\",
    \"oauth2.token.url\":\"xxxxxxx\",
    \"oauth2.client.id\":\"$OAUTH_ID\",
    \"oauth2.client.secret\":\"$OAUTH_SECRET\",
    \"oauth2.client.auth.mode\":\"header\",
    \"oauth2.client.headers\":\"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\",
    \"oauth2.client.scope\":\"$OAUTH_SCOPE\",
    \"oauth2.token.property\":\"access_token\",
    \"max.retries\": 1,
    \"consumer.override.group.id\":\"xxxxxxx\"
}"
```